# OpenGL ES Ortho2D rotate on its center

Tags: opengl-es

```
opengl.loadIdentity();
  opengl.translate(0,0,0);

   cnt++;
   opengl.saveMatrix();
       opengl.color4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.9f);

       opengl.selectVertex("proba2").translate(0, 0f, 4.2f-15);
       opengl.selectVertex("proba2").rotate((int) cnt, 0, 0, 1);

       opengl.selectVertex("proba2").draw(true);
   opengl.loadMatrix();

   opengl.saveMatrix();
   opengl.setOrthoStart();

       opengl.color4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.9f);

       opengl.selectVertex("proba3").translate(0, 200);
       opengl.selectVertex("proba3").rotate((int) cnt, 0, 0, 1);

       opengl.selectVertex("proba3").draw(true);
    opengl.setOrthoEnd();
    opengl.loadMatrix();
```

I have this code. On the first vertex (it is a 3d vertex), it work well, just rotating it around the Z axis (round by itself)

But the second state(2d vertex, ortho), when i am go to ortho2D, the Z axis rotating not working correctly, because its not rotating on its center point. Why?

Comment: nobody?:( in 2d the rotating point will be the top-left corner point. but in 3d the rotating point will be the object item center... why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was on my coords error

i add coords: 1, 100, 1, 100 (top, bottom, left right)

when i add: -50 50 -50 50 its work succesfull!